# Compare two text values of element tags in XPath Query

Tags: xpath

I have this XML code:

```
                
        <partit num="1">
            <equip juga="local">
                <nom>Verds</nom>
                <resultat>2</resultat>
            </equip>
            
            <equip juga="visitant">
                <nom>Blaus</nom>
                <resultat>2</resultat>
            </equip>            
        </partit>
        
        <partit num="2">
            <equip juga="local">
                <nom>Vermells</nom>
                <resultat>1</resultat>
            </equip>
            <equip juga="visitant">
                <nom>Blancs</nom>
                <resultat>1</resultat>
            </equip>
        </partit>
```

I need to find all Equip Nom that are Blancs and compare with the adversary Equip if they have the same amount of Gols (a tie or draw).

Comment: Could you please give some English  translations to the xml, so it is easier to understand what the goal is?

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution, it was more simple than I thought but it't nowhere documented:

```
count(//equip/nom[text()='Blancs']/following-sibling::resultat[text()=//equip/nom[text()='Blancs']/../following-sibling::equip/resultat])
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? I get `0` as a result.